# Java hangman help, my code included

Tags: java, oop

**Hello, I have to create a hangman game in java. I cant use arrays. Most of my code is done but I have been having some problems and some tips would be welcome.

---

I just found something else that I could use help on. After prompting the user for a new secret word and using newHangMan.setSecretWord(newWord); my disguised word does not reset to  "????" (with the same number of "?" as words in the secret word).

---

I'm very sorry for such a long post and the bad formatting(1st time posting here).
Can anyone help?**

This is my class file:

```
 public class HangMan 
{

private String secretWord = "bigbang",  disguisedWord = "";
private int guessCount = 0, missCount = 0;



public void setSecretWord(String newWord)
{
    secretWord = newWord;
    guessCount = 0;
    missCount = 0;

    int wordLength = newWord.length();
    while(wordLength > 0)
    {
        disguisedWord = disguisedWord + "?";
        wordLength--;
    }

}

public String getSecretWord()
{
    return secretWord;
}




 public boolean isFound()
 {  
    return secretWord.equalsIgnoreCase(disguisedWord);

 }


 public String getDisguisedWord()
 {
     return disguisedWord;
 }

 public int getGuessCount()
 {
     return guessCount;
 }

 public int getMissesCount()
 {
     return missCount;
 }

 public void guessCharacter(char c)
 {
    // int position = secretWord.indexOf(c);
     boolean got_it = false;
     String updateDisguised="";

     for(int i=0; i < secretWord.length();i++)
     {

         if(c == secretWord.charAt(i))
         {

             updateDisguised = updateDisguised + secretWord.charAt(i);

             String checkDuplicate = updateDisguised.substring(0,i);
             int duplicatePos = checkDuplicate.indexOf(c);
             if(duplicatePos <0)
                 guessCount++;
             got_it = true;


         }
         else 
         {
             updateDisguised = updateDisguised + disguisedWord.charAt(i);
         }

     }
     if(got_it == false)
     {
         missCount++;
         guessCount++;
     }


     disguisedWord = updateDisguised; 

 }










 }
```

**This is my main method:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;



 public class HangManGame {

public static void main(String[] args) 
{


    boolean retry= true;
    String retry_ans;

    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);


    HangMan newHangMan = new HangMan();

    String word = newHangMan.getSecretWord();
    String input;
    char guess;
     newHangMan.setSecretWord(word);

    System.out.println("Hangman game starts:");

do{


    System.out.println("Guess this: " + newHangMan.getDisguisedWord());
    System.out.println("Enter your guess character: [guess]");
    input = kb.next();
    guess = input.charAt(0);

    newHangMan.guessCharacter(guess);

    System.out.println(newHangMan.getDisguisedWord());

    System.out.println("Number of guesses so far : " + newHangMan.getGuessCount());
    System.out.println("NUmber of misses so far: " + newHangMan.getMissesCount());




    if((newHangMan.getMissesCount()==7) || (newHangMan.isFound()))
    {
        System.out.println("The game is over");

        System.out.println("Would you like to try again?");
        retry_ans = kb.next();
        if(retry_ans.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"))
        {
            retry = true;
            System.out.println("Please enter a new secret word:");
            String newWord = kb.next();
            newHangMan.setSecretWord(newWord);
        }
        else
        {
            retry =false;
        }

    }






    }   while(retry == true);




}
```

}

Comment: *It won't work* is a very bad description of your problem. Tell us what you expect, and what you have instead. Does it compile? Does it run, but with an exception? If so, what's the stack trace? Does it give an incorrect result for a given input? If so, what's the input, what's the expected result, and what's the effective result?

Comment: The problem I was having was that the game loop in the main method would not break when the method isFound() was satisfied. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(newHangMan.isFound()=true)
```

should be

```
newHangMan.isFound()
```

Do not make an bool compare to another bool.
The = is evaluate the `boolean`.

Comment: Wow, it was that easy. Now the loop stops when the words match. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I will ,when I can(reputation still too low).

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
while(retry = true);
```

with

```
while(retry);
```

The former is an assignment, so it never evaluates to `false` although it should.

Answer (score 1):

Your while condition is an assignment, rather than a comparison, which is likely the cause of your problem - you're setting the value of `retry` to `true` (`retry = true`) rather than checking that the value of `retry` currently equals true (`retry == true`).

Answer (score 0):

Classic java starter error. while check stetement should be

```
While(retry == true)
```